# SQL select only one row from second table JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following tables

**Channel**
| id | name | descr |

**channel_user**

| channel_id | user_id |

**channel_text**

| channel_id | text_id |

**text**

| id | text | time

I am trying to retrieve all channels a user is subscribed to along with the last time a channel has received a text (by user).
example:
| id | name | descr | lastUpdate

So far I have the following

```
SELECT c.*,t.time as lastUpdate  
FROM  chanel c 
  INNER JOIN chanel_user cu ON c.id = cu.chanel_id  
  INNER JOIN chanel_text ct ON cu.chanel_id=ct.chanel_id 
  INNER JOIN text t ON t.id=ct.text_id 
  JOIN (
      SELECT id,MAX(time) maxtime FROM text GROUP BY id
  ) b ON t.time = b.maxtime 
  JOIN users u ON cu.user_id=u.id 
WHERE  u.id=2 
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Comment: "retrieve all channels" from a table named "chanel" ?

Comment: My table is actually called chanel (misspelled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the `JOIN` between `channel_text` and `text` in the subquery.  Also there is no `u` table in your query, but it is not needed:

```
SELECT c.*, t.time as lastUpdate 
FROM chanel c INNER JOIN
     chanel_user cu
     ON t.id = ct.text_id JOIN
     (SELECT ct.chanel_id, MAX(time) as maxtime
      FROM chanel_text ct JOIN
           text t
           ON ct.text_id = t.id
      GROUP BY ct.chanel_id
     ) ct
     ON cu.chanel_id = ct.chanel_id
WHERE cu.id = 2
ORDER BY c.id;
```